# Droid X - is Blur home running when you use Launcher Pro?

Tags: home-screen, motorola-droid-x, launcher, motoblur

Based on the process list in ATK, it appears that Blur home (including the widgets) are loaded and running - and can't be turned off in any way - when you are using Launcher Pro as your home replacement.

- Is this an accurate observation?
- Is there a way to stop any of the Blur **widget** processes from starting (rooted but standard ROM) completely? Just to clarify, "replace with Blur-less ROM" is not a satisfactory answer, since Cyanogen doesn't run on DroidX due to locked bootloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's an accurate observation.

I don't have a Motorola phone myself, but from what I understand Blur is embedded pretty tightly into the ROM.  Trying to remove it would be painful at best, and probably just cause your phone to start crashing.  I'd recommend flashing a custom ROM that either never had Blur (e.g. something built largely from the AOSP like CyanogenMOD) or a heavily customized version of your ROM that has had Blur thoroughly rooted out and replaced with stock apps.

Comment: there don't appear to be any fully stable/functional DroidX ROMs at first glance. CyanogenMOD is explicitly out of the question due to X's locked bootloader

Comment: also, I didn't ask about removing Blur. I asked about stopping (permanently) system processes that are specifically related to Blur widgets (like `com.motorola.blur.weather`/`...news` etc...

Comment: Liberty is pretty nice for the Droid X and the newer GB versions seem to allow you to pick and choose if you want Blur available (I haven't checked the ATK though).

Comment: @DVK You can't just stop it, that's the point. It either has to run or to be removed and replaced.